# Expectation problem using empirical distribution

Tags: probability-or-statistics

I am having trouble with this Mathematica command:

```
 Probability[ x + y + z > 14, {x, y, z} \[Distributed] 
 ProductDistribution[{DiscreteUniformDistribution[{1, 6}], 3}]]`
```

outputs 5 / 54. What I would like to do is use the EmpiricalDistribution sort of like this:

```
 Probability[x + y + z > 14, {x, y, z} \[Distributed]
 ProductDistribution[{EmpiricalDistribution[{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}], 3}]]
```

of course, that does not work and just spits out the command. How can I get the Empirical Distribution to work like that?

Comment: Does this do what you want? `Probability[
 x + y + z > 
  14, {x, y, z} \[Distributed] 
   EmpiricalDistribution[{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}] // Thread]`

Comment: Hi Rojo; Yes, that seems to work fine. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a possibility

```
Probability[
    x + y + z > 14, 
   {x, y, z} \[Distributed] 
        EmpiricalDistribution[{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}] // Thread
 ]
```

Comment: that's very interesting. I don't understand what the `Thread` is doing. Threading the EmpiricalDistribution gives: `{DataDistribution["Empirical", {1/6, 1/6, 1/6, 1/6, 1/6, 1/6}, 1, 6], 
 DataDistribution["Empirical", {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}, 1, 6], 
 DataDistribution["Empirical", False, 1, 6]}`. Only the middle one of these seems to make sense.

Comment: @bills, the `EmpiricalDistribution` by itself evaluates to the `DataDistribution`. Here I am not threading the `EmpiricalDistribution` but the whole `Distributed[{x,y,z},Emp...]` (check the precedences). So, just like `f[{a, b, c}, 2] // Thread` gives `{f[a, 2], f[b,2], f[c,2]}`, this is equivalent to `{Distributed[x, Emp[...]], Distributed[y, Emp[...]], Distributed[z, Emp[...]]}`

Comment: I get it now! This is saying that `x`, `y`, and `z` are each distributed like the `EmpiricalDistribution`. The `Thread` is over the two lines of code, not just over the third line. Thanks for clarifying!

Comment: @bills no problem :)

Comment: @ bill s; Thanks for asking what I was thinking too.